# what is wrong with this code in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my console the error is coming "getIdData is not defined" what is wrong with my code. Here deal is my service and getIdData is my function in service.

```
$scope.editUserDetail = function editUserDetail(){
        $scope.showEditView = !$scope.showEditView;
        $scope.showSubmitView = !$scope.showSubmitView;
        console.log(deal);
        deal.getIdData().then(function successCb(data){
            $scope.editIdOptionsData=data;  
        });
};
```

Comment: have you defined "getIdData" function in "deal" ?

Comment: since `deal` is your service it should be injected inside your controller not passed in as a parameter to your function. Also, as you can probably see in your `console.log(deal)` there should not be any `getIdData()` function. Please add the entirely controller and service code so we have more details to work with.

Comment: Yeah Umer.. I have defined "getIdData" function in "deal" and In "getIdData" I am calling my API like  service.getIdData = function(data,accountId,decisionMakerDetail){
      var def = $q.defer();
      var url = baseUrl + '/api/accountsusers/' + accountId + '?role=' + decisionMakerDetail;
      httpHelper._$http({
        method: 'post', url: url,  data: data, def: def
      }, function (resp) {
        def.resolve(resp.msg);
      });
      return def.promise;
    };

Comment: Hey aldolfosrs.. I have already injected "deal" service in controller.

Comment: @VishakhaNehe so why are you setting the service as a parameter to your $scope function? there is no need for this. please edit the question adding your service code.

Comment: Could you provide some more code, like with service?

Comment: Service function  is service.getIdData = function(data,accountId,decisionMakerDetail){
      var def = $q.defer();
      var url = baseUrl + '/api/accountsusers/' + accountId + '?role=' + decisionMakerDetail;
      httpHelper._$http({
        method: 'post', url: url,  data: data, def: def
      }, function (resp) {
        def.resolve(resp.msg);
      });
      return def.promise;
    };

Comment: And there is a on click function in which I need to show some response so I am writing over there like :  $scope.editUserDetail = function editUserDetail(){
        $scope.showEditView = !$scope.showEditView;
        $scope.showSubmitView = !$scope.showSubmitView;
        deal.getIdData().then(function successCb(data){
          $scope.editIdOptionsData=data;
      });
    };

Comment: Sorry I was not clear with my request. Could you update your question with service and controller injections with code syntaxfor readability. That way we can help you better. And please try to provide a bit more code.

Comment: @infernaze My service is : angular.module('account')
  .service('deal', function deal($http, accountConfiguration, $q, $log,  httpHelper) {
    var service = {};
    var baseUrl = account.app.url;
    service.getIdData = function(data,accountId,decisionMakerDetail){
      var def = $q.defer();
      var url = baseUrl + '/api/accountsusers/' + accountId + '?role=' + decisionMakerDetail;
      httpHelper._$http({
        method: 'post', url: url,  data: data, def: def
      }, function (resp) {
        def.resolve(resp.msg);
      });
      return def.promise;
    };

Comment: My controller is : angular.module('account')
  .controller('DealDetailCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, deal,account,$filter,toastMessage,$state,componentState) {
$scope.editUserDetail = function editUserDetail(){
        $scope.showEditView = !$scope.showEditView;
        deal.getIdData().then(function successCb(data){
          $scope.editIdOptionsData=data;
      });
    };

Comment: You are not returning the servuce refernce from your service. See the explanation and fix in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Please check working example here: [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/G4ocFbzzdVjzUAErAsRy?p=preview)

You are forget to return service object from service.

i.e

Write following code in your service,

```
return service;
```

i.e

```
angular.module('account').service('deal', function deal($http, accountConfiguration, $q, $log, httpHelper) {
     var service = {};
     var baseUrl = account.app.url;
     service.getIdData = function(data, accountId, decisionMakerDetail) {
            var def = $q.defer();
            var url = baseUrl + '/api/accountsusers/' + accountId + '?role=' + decisionMakerDetail;
            httpHelper._$http({
                      method: 'post',
                      url: url,
                      data: data,
                      def: def
             }, function(resp) {
                 def.resolve(resp.msg);
             });
             return def.promise;
      };

      return service;
});
```

Or as you are using service you can write it using **this**

```
angular.module('account').service('deal', function deal($http, accountConfiguration, $q, $log, httpHelper) {

     var baseUrl = account.app.url;
     this.getIdData = function(data, accountId, decisionMakerDetail) {
            var def = $q.defer();
            var url = baseUrl + '/api/accountsusers/' + accountId + '?role=' + decisionMakerDetail;
            httpHelper._$http({
                      method: 'post',
                      url: url,
                      data: data,
                      def: def
             }, function(resp) {
                 def.resolve(resp.msg);
             });
             return def.promise;
      };

  });
```

For more information please check - [Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Answer (score 0):

The object you are sending as a parameter doesn't have the getIdData() function defined.

Change your log to:

```
console.log(deal.getIdData);
```

and then check whether it returns the function code/definition.

Here is a link with an example of how implement a factory and service.
[Angular factory and service](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_services.htm)

Comment: Still this is showing "getIdData is not a function". I am adding console to see the result only. If I will remove that then shows same.

Answer (score 0):

Please clean your browser and inspect source.Look deal.getIdData() is loaded or not.May be it is not loaded.Please load properly.

Comment: Hey .. Still this is showing "getIdData is not a function". I am adding console to see the result only. If I will remove that then shows same.

Comment: Don't remove getIdData function just inspect browser and go to source option and ensure service loaded and  function loaded into browser successfully.Then try again.

Comment: I am trying debugger to check that but debugger does not comes to that service. On hover "getIdData" it is showing undefined. Although I have created a function with this name in my service in which I am calling my API.

Comment: Delete your cache from browser.Do you inject your service into controller? just like this app.controller('IssueCtrl', ['$scope', 'Service',
    function ($scope, Service) {}

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the object holding the service reference from you your service registration function. Change your code as below for it to work.

```
angular.module('account')
   .service('deal', function deal($http, accountConfiguration, $q, $log,  httpHelper) {
     var service = {};
     var baseUrl = account.app.url;

     service.getIdData = function(data,accountId,decisionMakerDetail){
        var def = $q.defer();
        var url = baseUrl + '/api/accountsusers/' + accountId + '?role=' + decisionMakerDetail;

        httpHelper._$http({
          method: 'post', url: url,  data: data, def: def
        }, function (resp) {
           def.resolve(resp.msg);
        });
          return def.promise;
     };

  return service;
});
```

S8nce you were not returning anything from the service, even though `deal` service gets registered, its value is undefined and when you try to access `deal.getIddata()` you get the aforementioned error